# VTK continous display multiple images

Tags: c++, vtk

I am a newcomer for VTK .I want to display three images,and update it,like video. I use example [MultipleViewports](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/MultipleViewports) show three picture.

- 1.`mapper->SetInputConnection(sphereSource->GetOutputPort());`,how to change a matrix to type `(vtkAlgorithmOutput *input)`?
- 2.After `renderWindowInteractor->Start();`, this program stops. How could I change the image data and fresh it? Another better ideas is welcome.
  Thanks.

Comment: For second question, I could say that you should put your code inside of a framework, to get rid of renderWindowInteractor->Start() ... then, you will have a full control on program flowing ...

Comment: @flaviu2 ,Thank you for your replying, and Sorry for the delayed response. You are right, and I use this code `renderWindow->Render(); renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)` will work. Thank you again.